# stored procedure update retain values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, update

In SQL Server, when using optional parameters, the only way to have default values is using `@param = NULL` upon creating.

Is there a way for the stored procedure to know that the application will only update specific columns and the remaining columns will retain the original values?

Here is my example:

Data: `col1 = "AA" col2 = "BB" col3 = "CC"`

Application update inside stored procedure: `UPDATE table SET col3 = "C", col ="B" WHERE id = 1`

After update, value of col1 will remain.

I hope my explanation is clear enough :)

Comment: Additional question, Is it also advisable to combine inserting and updating records in a same stored procedure (Logic: if insert, insert records, if update, update record)?

Comment: You can use IF ELSE for check all parameters and prepare statements, than execute it. and Yes - You can have in same procedure as much number of operations as You need. Again by parameters You can manage - do all of them of just selected

Comment: If you are only concerned with not updating those columns that have NULL parameters you could also go with col3 = COALESCSE(@param, col3)...

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, if stored procedure is called with @vCol1 = 'AA', @vCol2 = 'BB' and @vCol3 = NULL then you want to update only Col1 and Col2 keeping the Col3 value intact.
Then you can go with the following solution. I agree its not the best one but it will get work done in simple manner.

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = ISNULL(@vCol1, col1)
  , col2 = ISNULL(@vCol2, col2)
  , col3 = ISNULL(@vCol3, col3)
WHERE id = 1
```